# How to set window.opener in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.opener

I have old code, which uses window.opener. I changed opening method of these pages from popup to iframe in a jquery dialog. That works fine with IE and Chrome, where I only need to reset window.opener in onload event. But Firefox does not play ball. It sets opener to null regardless what the opener was or is to be set (which is ludicrous). Is there a way to change window.opener in Firefox? I known I could work around it by storing the opener information elsewhere, but it takes a lot of more changes.

Comment: We cannot predict your current code, so we are unable to help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ludicrous to prevent you overriding read-only properties of host objects. In short, no there is no way to change it. What you need to do is string replace all references to window.opener with a different value and place the object you're interested in there.

Comment: Why then change it to null? And it works with IE and Chrome. In Chrome it works at least in same domain.

Comment: I am a little surprised about it changing to null. In your use case it sounds like it should be null already anyway, however, modifying host object like this is prone to undefined behaviour. You really shouldn't be modifying or attempting to modify this property in any case, so the behaviour is irrelevant.

Comment: It's a known bug in Chrome that it allows setting window.opener to random values.  Per spec, the only value you can change it to is null.